# I cant transfer the next file using auto_route

Tags: flutter, dart, auto-route

My problem is the code of the router wont work
I want to transfer from one screen or file to another using auto_route.
My problem is routing in the menuItem and in the onPressed in the Positioned.
When I tap it, it shows this error "AutoRouter operation requested with a context that does not include an AutoRouter"

```
      `Positioned(
            top: 40,
            left: 20,
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.info,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  AutoRouter.of(context).push(Instruction() as PageRouteInfo);
                })),

        Positioned(
          top: size.height * 0.52,
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Menu',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                      children: [
                        Hero(
                          tag: 'humay',
                          child: MenuItem(

                            title: 'Humay',
                            assetName: 'assets/images/rice.svg',
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => const CalculatePage(
                                    plantEnum: PlantEnum.rice,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },

                          ),
                        ),
                        MenuItem(
                          title: 'Mga datus',
                          assetName: 'assets/images/to-do-list.svg',
                          onTap: () {
                            AutoRouter.of(context).push(const SaveData());
                          },
                        ),
                        MenuItem(
                          title: 'Tempo',
                          assetName: 'assets/images/sunny.svg',
                          onTap: () {
                            context.router.push(const WeatherRoute());
                          },
                        ),
                        MenuItem(
                          title: 'Guidlines',
                          assetName: 'assets/images/guideline.svg',
                          onTap: () {

                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),`
```

////main.dart

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initHive();

  await initSettings();
  //await initNotification();
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => WeatherProvider()),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

Future<void> initSettings() async {
  await Settings.init(
    cacheProvider: _isUsingHive ? HiveCache() : SharePreferenceCache(),
  );
}

bool _isUsingHive = true;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppRouter appRouter = AppRouter();
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Mag-uuma',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       // onGenerateRoute: appRouter.AppRouter(),
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: const Color(0xFF00838f),
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            hintColor: Color(0xFFf50057),
            fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
        home: FutureBuilder(
          future: Future.wait([Hive.openBox<Farm>('farmBox')]),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.error != null) {
                print(snapshot.error);
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text('Something went wrong :/'),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Navigator(
                  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                    return MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomePage(),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            } else {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text('Opening Hive...'),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        )

    );
  }
}
```

My problem is the code of the router wont work
I want to transfer from one screen or file to another using auto_route.
My problem is routing in the menuItem and in the onPressed in the Positioned.

Comment: Pls share your MaterialApp

Comment: I already edited my post

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

If you are using auto_route your MaterialApp widget should look like this

```
 return MaterialApp.router(
          /// I have used the injectable package to inject the AppRouter class.
          routerConfig: locator<AppRouter>().config(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: regularTheme,
          darkTheme: darkTheme,
          themeMode: themeMode,
          localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
          supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
          locale: context.locale,
        );
```

And that's it Example AppRouter class

```
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [

        AutoRoute(page: HomeViewRoute.page, initial: true),
     
      ];
}
```

You should mark the screen pages using annotations in this way and create the app_router_gr.dart class with auto_route_generator.

```
@RoutePage(name: 'HomeViewRoute')
final class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
```

and lastly you can use this method now.

```
 /// Instruction should really be a PageRouteInfo you shouldn't change its type with 'as'
    AutoRouter.of(context).push(Instruction() as PageRouteInfo)
```

And remember, if you want to set the login screen asynchronously based on data, you should use RouteGuard.

```
final class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  factory AuthGuard() => instance;

  AuthGuard._internal();
  static final AuthGuard instance = AuthGuard._internal();

  @override
  Future<void> onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
    final farmBox = await Hive.openBox<Farm>('farmBox');

    ///
    /// I just want to show you an example
    /// You can edit thats part as you want
    ///
    if (farmBox.isEmpty) {
      router.push(SomeRoute());
    }

    //     Remember, if you want the routeguard to continue on its way, finish it with resolver.next().

    // You can develop a control mechanism for this, because if you tell RouteGuard to go the same way again, it will enter a loop, be careful.

    resolver.next();

   
  }
}
```

Example AppRouter after added RouteGuard

```
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
     
        AutoRoute(
          page: HomeViewRoute.page,
          initial: true,
          guards: [AuthGuard()],
        ),
      
      ];
}
```